# Standard value for quality attribute in PHP's imagepng() function

Tags: php, gd

According to PHP's official documentation the imagepng() function has the following signature:

```
bool imagepng ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality [, int $filters ]]] )
```

What I need to know now is what the standard value of $quality is. I cannot find it anywhere in the documentation.

Is there some source that explains it or anyone who knows about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from php source (gd.h):

```
/* 2.0.12: Compression level: 0-9 or -1, where 0 is NO COMPRESSION at all,
* 1 is FASTEST but produces larger files, 9 provides the best
* compression (smallest files) but takes a long time to compress, and
* -1 selects the default compiled into the zlib library.
*/
```

Conclusion:
Based on the Zlib manual (http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) the default compression level is set to 6.

Answer (score 1):

from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

> Compression level: from 0 (no
> compression) to 9.

default value is 0

Comment: that was not my question. i want to know the value PHP takes, if I do not specify one

Comment: very simple: look at the source, or save the images 11 times with no value and each of the 0-9 values. Whichever one matches the "no value" save is your default.

Answer (score 0):

In php's source code quality parameter was defaulted to 0. But i havent idea for which value is optimal for image processing.

```
static void _php_image_output(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS, int image_type, char *tn, void (*func_p)())
{
    zval *imgind;
    char *file = NULL;
    long quality = 0, type = 0;
```